# In a form in React JS, the value of the field below move upwards to be the value of the field above, when the value of the field above is empty

Tags: reactjs, image, button, tailwind-css, textfield

I'm working on a project using React JS, Tailwind CSS. And this is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavbarStudent, Footer } from "../../../components";

const Profile = ({ name, id, email }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [major, setMajor] = useState("");
  const [intake, setIntake] = useState("");
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");
  const [storeMajor, setStoreMajor] = useState("");
  const [storeIntake, setStoreIntake] = useState("");
  const [storePhoneNumber, setStorePhoneNumber] = useState("");

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setShow(false);
    setMajor(storeMajor);
    setIntake(storeIntake);
    setPhoneNumber(storePhoneNumber);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <NavbarStudent></NavbarStudent>
      <div className="flex flex-row mr-72">
        {/* First column */}
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-2/5 mt-10 ml-20">
          <img src="avatar.png" alt="profile picture" loading="lazy"></img>

          {!show ? (
            <button
              onClick={() => setShow(true)}
              className="bg-[#CC6666] opacity-80 px-10 rounded-xl border hover:border-slate-500 mt-8 text-3xl text-[#1B1C1E] font-dongle"
            >
              Edit
            </button>
          ) : (
            <div
              className="flex justify-center items-center"
              class="ml-3 space-x-10 w-72 mt-8"
            >
              <button
                className="bg-[#CC6666] opacity-80 px-10 rounded-xl text-3xl text-[#1B1C1E] border hover:border-slate-500 font-dongle"
                onClick={() => {
                  setShow(false);
                  if (major !== "") {
                    setStoreMajor(major);
                  } else {
                    setStoreMajor(storeMajor);
                  }
                  setStoreIntake(intake);
                  setStorePhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                }}
              >
                Save
              </button>
              <button
                className="border-[#B02B3B] border-4 box-border w-28 h-9 pb-8 rounded-xl hover:border-slate-500 text-3xl ml-4 bg-[#ffffff] drop-shadow-[0_4px_1px_rgba(0,0,0,0.25)] text-[#1B1C1E]"
                onClick={handleCancel}
              >
                Cancel
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>

        {/* Second column */}
        <div className="w-3/12 text-5xl text-[#1B1C1E] font-semibold ml-28 space-y-6 mt-36">
          <p>Full name:</p>
          <p>ID:</p>
          <p>Email:</p>
          <p>Major:</p>
          <p>Intake:</p>
          <p>Phone number:</p>
        </div>

        {/* Third column */}
        <div className="w-1/12 text-5xl font-semibold mr-48 space-y-6 mt-36">
          <p>{name}</p>
          <p>{id}</p>
          <p>{email}</p>
          <p>
            {show ? (
              <input
                type="text"
                id="major"
                name="major"
                className="bg-[#CC6666]/30 rounded-2xl h-10 w-96 text-[#1B1C1E] px-3"
                value={major}
                onChange={(e) => setMajor(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
            ) : (
              <span>{storeMajor}</span>
            )}
          </p>
          <p>
            {show ? (
              <input
                type="text"
                id="intake"
                name="intake"
                className="bg-[#CC6666]/30 rounded-2xl h-10 w-96 text-[#1B1C1E] px-3"
                value={intake}
                onChange={(e) => setIntake(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
            ) : (
              storeIntake
            )}
          </p>

          <p>
            {show ? (
              <input
                type="text"
                id="phoneNumber"
                name="phoneNumber"
                className="bg-[#CC6666]/30 rounded-2xl h-10 w-96 text-[#1B1C1E] px-3"
                value={phoneNumber}
                onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
            ) : (
              storePhoneNumber
            )}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

I have 2 problems:

The first probem is that: for example, I click the edit button, I enter the value for the major and intake field, then I click save button. Then I click edit button again, I delete the major value only, keep the intake value remains the same. Then I click save button. I expect that: the UI will show nothing in the major value (because I've just deleted its value), keep the value of intake remains the same, and AT THE SAME POSITION as it is. But the thing is, the value of intake moves upwards, to be the value of the major value (which, I expect, its value should be empty). I don't know why. I think the reason could be that: because the major value is empty, so the intake value moves upwards to occupy the value of major. It also happens the same to the rest of the input fields.

The second problem is that: everytime I click any button, the image (which is a circle) moves a little bit. I want the image to be fixed at its original position, do not change position when I click any button. I think the reason could be that: the margin of the buttons below is so large that it may push the image upwards when I click it.

Could you please help me with these 2 problems? Thanks a BILLION!

Here are the images:
[[This is the image of the UI at the beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIeJS.png)]

[This is the UI after I click edit button:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9KAk.png)

I have mentioned what I've tried above.

Comment: Could you mirror the project or minimum evidence to reproduce those problems on other platforms i.e: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? It's hard to indicate where those problems exactly come from.

Comment: Dear @HuyPham I'm sorry, I'm just newbie, and due to limit of time, I can't mirror the project to reproduce the same problems on other platforms. But I would appreciate that we can contact via email,fb,...or something, so that I could specify it in more details. Thanks a lot.